# C# Deserialize lists within a .dat file to a text box

Tags: c#, loops, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I have created an application that will save lists to a .dat file using a binary formatter and serializing the list.

I wish to then de serialize this list and display this within a text box.

Furthermore, I have tried using a for each loop to get every object from the list, but it won't continue through the rest of the lists and stops at the first list stored within the file.

I have been tasked with binary formatter even though Ive been informed its obsolete.

```
`public InPerson(int iId, string sDate, string sTime, string sDuration, string sPatientname, string 
sPhonenumber, string sDoctorid, string sRoomnumber, string sNurseid)
{
    this.iId = iId;
    this.sDate = sDate;
    this.sTime = sTime;
    this.sDuration = sDuration;
    this.sPatientname = sPatientname;
    this.sPhonenumber = sPhonenumber;
    this.sDoctorid = sDoctorid;
    this.sRoomnumber = sRoomnumber;
    this.sNurseid = sNurseid;
}

//To String method for saving
        public override string ToString()
        {
        return "In Person Apppointment:  " + iId + System.Environment.NewLine +
        "Date:  " + sDate + System.Environment.NewLine +
        "Time:  " + sTime + System.Environment.NewLine +
        "Duration:  " + sDuration + System.Environment.NewLine +
        "Patients Name: " + sPatientname + System.Environment.NewLine +     "Patients Number: " + sPhonenumber + System.Environment.NewLine +
    "Doctors ID:  " + sDoctorid + System.Environment.NewLine +
    "Room Number: " + sRoomnumber + System.Environment.NewLine +
    "Nurse id:  " + sNurseid + System.Environment.NewLine + "";
}

InPerson NewInPersonApp = new InPerson(Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text), dateTimePickerBooking.Text, txtTime.Text, txtDuration.Text, txtPatientName.Text, txtPhoneNumber.Text, txtDoctorID.Text, txtRoomAllocated.Text, txtNurseID.Text);
    

    List<InPerson> InPersonList = new List<InPerson>();
    
    InPersonList.Add(NewInPersonApp);
    
    const String filename = "appointments.dat";
    
    FileStream outFile;
    
    BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    
    outFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
    
    bFormatter.Serialize(outFile, InPersonList);
    
    outFile.Close();`
`



I wish to use this code to loop every list out from the file.

`InPersonList = (List<InPerson>)bFormatter.Deserialize(inFile);

foreach (InPerson a in InPersonList)
{
    txtBookings.Text += a.ToString();
}`
```

Comment: Unless we know what you *wrote* to the file, we will not be able to assist you in reading from it. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You didn't post any code that generates this file. What you posted generates strings, not binary files. `BinaryFormatter` is obsolete and uses a proprietary format that's highly insecure. It's not meant for reading binary data in general. If you're looking for a way to persist data in a binary format, there are far better, standardized formats like Protobuf

Comment: You really, really shouldn't be using BinaryFormatter at all. It's not just obsolete, it's being removed from the .NET runtime little by little. [As the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-7.0#remarks) *BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure. For more information, see the [BinaryFormatter security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide).*

Comment: I have been tasked to use this so dont have a choice unfortunately

Comment: The only reason to use binaryFormatter today is if you need to read old data or interface with old systems. Newer alternatives like json, xml or protobuf (and others, these are just the ones I have used) are better in every way. If you should push back against unreasonable demands, you are (presumably) being hired for your technical competence to select appropriate solutions for things like this.